# What is naming convention for subtitle files?

Tags: filenames, media

I use VLC that automatically opens subtitles with same name as movie:

```
Movie:    [Name].avi
Sutitles: [Name].srt
```

But i wonder how should i name subtitles if i have more than one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just add the name of the language between the movie name and the extension:

Just like:

```
Movie: [Name].avi
English Subtitles:[Name].en.srt
French Subtitles: [Name].fr.srt
Spanish Subtitles: [Name].es.srt
```

Comment: What if there's more than one file for the same language? E.g., multiple translations.

Comment: I believe it should work fine if you just append numbers as well, ie: [Name}.en1.srt

Comment: What if one srt contains dual language subtitles, for example both English and Spanish? More info: [tool to create them](https://subtitletools.com/merge-subtitles-online), [reasoning behind](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/dual-subtitles/).